# Knowing a file has been archived on ext4 file system

Tags: linux, logfile, inode, ext4

I need to find a way to determine whether a file has been archived (mainly using logrotate).
On **BTRFS**, the inode is changing when creating a new file with the same name.

But on the **ext4** filesystem, it seems to not be the case.

The scenario is the following:  a process is creating and feeding a Linux logfile on a dedicated path on a **ext4** filesystem. At some point in time, it's rotated using the logrotate process. But re-created with the same path later on.

It seems the (inode,dev) combination is not sufficient to uniquely determine with no doubt whether the file has been rotated.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304087/64699

Comment: There must be a way, `tail -F ` certainly reports it correctly.